# How do I use zlib to compress a File stream on the fly in ruby

Tags: ruby, zlib

I'd like to wrap a normal file in such a way that reading from it (in chunks) yields compressed data.

currently:

```
f = File.open(name)

while(string = f.read(@chunk_size) {
    <do something>
}
```

How would I use Zlib such that f.read returns @chunk_size of compressed data?

I found an example like the below where 'str' can be used, but it relies on reading the entire file at once which isn't possible as it could be a very large file.

```
str = StringIO.new()
gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(str)
gz.write File.read('local-file.txt')
gz.close

str.string.read(@chunk_size)
```

thanks

UPDATE:

this hack seems to work, but I'm sure it could be instrumented with Zlib:

```
f = File.popen("/bin/gzip < #{name}" )
```

looking into how to do with Zlib..

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the file is in separate lines, you may use the each_line() iterator method

```
f = File.new('somefile.txt', 'r')
f.each_line do |line|
  <The compression and storage part>
end
```

Probably this might've occured to you already.

Comment: unfortunately it's a binary file so I don't think an "each_line" would work here